# unable to install naoqi

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following the beginner tutorial
--Getting start with ROS for the Nao, including NAOqi and rviz.

I was unable to download the 1.14.3 sdk from the aldebaran website so i did it from some other site. When i am trying to run naoqi and executing this command:

$ ~/naoqi/naoqi-sdk-1.12.3-linux32/naoqi

I get an error saying no such file or directory. WHen I cehck the home folder, the file is there in the folder. How do I proceed? How do I install naoqi?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/98196/unable-to-install-naoqi/) by [uzair](https://answers.ros.org/users/8341/uzair/) on ROS Answers with karma: 87 on 2013-11-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Menglord](https://answers.ros.org/users/9206/menglord/) on 2013-12-02**:
where did you find the SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Best request support from Aldebaran, they supply the NaoQI SDK. This has nothing to do with ROS, so the question is not really suited for this site.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2013-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0